# Okta warning message while running application

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, okta

While trying to run the application from VM getting the warning as below and application not started.

```
level=WARN thread_id=main class=com.okta.spring.boot.oauth.env.OktaEnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener method=onApplicationEvent line=38 Your Okta Issuer URL is missing. You can copy your domain from the Okta Developer Console. Follow these instructions to find it in okta page
To fix this add the `okta.oauth2.issuer` property to your application.
```

try running the jar file in local profile with supporting DB connection.

Comment: Did you try adding `okta.oauth2.issuer` to your yml file ? If you can share more code or yml this question will be clearer

Comment: im trying to run application in my local 
here the yaml

Comment: im trying to run application in my local 
here the yaml
but other envs like dev and stage have okta issuer configured
**`
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: local
    properties:
      '[org.quartz.threadPool]':
        threadCount: 4
  freemarker:
    cache: false
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
  datasource:
    hikari:
      minimum-idle: 2
      maximum-pool-size: 10`**